# Communicating and comparing between objects in python-multiprocessing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to find a way to compare between different objects (inherited from Thread class) in a way that keep parallilsm (real-time processing).

Every worker has three fields (message, count, n ). I am updating `Count` everytime. Let's say that I have three threads `workers`. I need to compare in my server based on the field `count`, how can I do access and compare between `Worker.count` of every worker, in a way that I keep parallelism

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

import time

class Worker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, message, n):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        self.count= 0
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(self.message)
            self.count+=1
            time.sleep(self.n)

class Comparator(Thread):

    def __init__(self, message, n):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        while True:
            max= max([x.count for x in threads]) # how can I access to other threads 
            print  "max", max
            time.sleep(self.n)



thread1 = Worker("Test-1", 1)
thread2 = Worker("Test-2", 3)


s = Comparator("Test-3", 2)

s.start()
s.join()

threads = [thread1, thread2]

for g in threads:
    g.start()

for worker in threads:
      # wait for workers
      worker.join()
```

**NOTE** Using shared object here is not a good solution for me, using Queue() for example is not what I want, I need to do comparision based on updated field in the object that I update on the go (for simplicity, I use max() ).

Answer (score -1):

you can pass the `threads` list to `Comparator` `__init__()` method :

```
[...]
class Comparator(Thread):

    def __init__(self, message, n, threads):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threads = threads

    def run(self):
        while True:
            max= max([x.count for x in self.threads]) 
            print("max", max)
            time.sleep(self.n)

[...]
threads = [thread1, thread2]
s = Comparator("Test-3", 2, threads)
```

Comment: Is this the right way to do it ? Talking about the best practices  here.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if anyone would care to comment on this I would be glad to read.